# Qt serial port: write and read data

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtcore, qtserialport

I'm able to connect to my serial port, but I need to read data from it all the time.
It's working for about 39 minutes, but after it stops at line `serial.flush()`.
When I stop Qt and start it again it also stops at `serial.flush()`.  I need to restart my modem to let it work again...

I'm not sure I'm executing this properly...

```
// Open Serial connexion
QSerialPort serial;
serial.setPortName("usbserial-26214A");
serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::HardwareControl);

if (serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable())
{
qDebug() << "Serial is open";

QByteArray output;
QByteArray input;

  while(true)
  {
  output = "AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\r";
  serial.write(output);
  serial.flush();
  serial.waitForBytesWritten(1000);
  serial.waitForReadyRead(1000);
  input = serial.readAll();
  }
}
```

//EDIT

if deleting `flush` it's working, but code goes really fast. It don't wait for `WaitFor...`
After 2nd loop he doesn't has time to read data.

`serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable()` always sends `true` in while loop.

**Program stops at `flush` after 30 minutes!**

Comment: If waitForBytesWritten() it should be safe to omit the flush(). I guess this won't solve the problem though. Is it possible to just run a soft-reset always before AT+CPMS Sequence? Not sure the connection problem is related to your application.

Comment: If deleting `flush` line, loop goes really fast and don't seems to `waitFor...`. How to do a *soft-reset*?

Comment: Does the application continue by simply powercycling the modem ? Or do you also have to restart the App ? In the first case I would assume that the modem got stuck. May be you should debug the state the modem is in and check if there are commands to revitalize it.

Comment: By powercycling the modem it works. I also have to restart the app because I can't find errors... `serial.isOpen() || serial.isWritable()`is true and `serial.errorString` is null

Comment: Why are you blocking in the first place? Why are you not utilizing the async API?

Comment: How to do that? Can that solve the problem?

Comment: Check [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtserialport-cwriterasync-serialportwriter-cpp.html) out. I wrote this example a while ago, so basically, you would put your readAll() call into the handle bytes written slot. It does not necessarily solve your issue, but it will get you going, and you should be writing your code like this anyway.

Comment: Thank you I'll change that, but any idea why `flush` isn't working after 30 minutes? and working again when powercycling the modem?

Comment: No idea, but you could also try to open in unbuffered mode instead of flush.

Answer (score 0):

If `serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable()` is true in while loop, but you can't access it could come from you preferences on your computer.

On OSX: System preferences -> network -> select serial -> advanced -> PPP:
able: Ask to stay connected every 10 minutes,
disable: disconnect at close of session,
disable: disconnect when changing of user